# Will iOS system discard the shared cookies after 24 hours

Tags: ios

in iOS app, "Cookie" header is being discarded or removed from HTTP shared cookie header after 24 hours. In cookie header only we are sending access token which we used for mobile API.

My question is, iOS system will automatically delete or remove or discard cookie header for security purpose ?